# how to set delta in column name of flextable R

Tags: r, flextable

I have a data frame and want to use greek characters in the column name of a formatted flextable.

```
df = data.frame(col1=1:4, col2 = 5:8)
nm = c('category', '\u394')
colnames(df) = nm
df
df %>% flextable()
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, col_keys) : undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In do.call(data.frame, c(x, alis)) :
  unable to translate '<U+0394>' to native encoding
```

I did find this while working:

- I can include unicode in the column values ok:

  `df = data.frame(col1=1:4, col2 = c('\u394', "Δ", "\u20ac", "€"))`

  `df %>% flextable()`

[image]

- I can add an extra header row with the delta sign in place with:

`df %>% flextable() %>% add_header_row(values = c("Category", "\u394"))`

[image]

Is there any suggestions how to get a column name to be Δ by not adding an extra header row, because the output would have an extra header row?

Answer (score 0):

found a solution using function `set_header_labels()`

```
data.frame(col1=1:4, col2 = c('\u394', "Δ", "\u20ac", "€")) %>% flextable() %>%
  set_header_labels(values = list(col1 = "COL1",
                                  col2 = "\u394m"))
```

[image]